# Failed to construct 'OfflineAudioContext'?

Tags: web-audio-api

I'm constructing an Offline Audio Context on a web page. When I refresh the page, sometimes, it works. Sometimes it doesn't.

```
var context = new OfflineAudioContext(2, 29445571, 44100);
```

The error in the console when it doesn't work:

```
NotSupportedError: Failed to construct 'OfflineAudioContext': 
OfflineAudioContext(2, 29445571, 44100);
```

What's this error even hinting at? What's unsupported?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely this is saying that it couldn't allocate enough memory to hold the result. You're asking for 2*29445571 frames of data or about 224 MB of memory.  Depending on what else is going on, you may have run out of memory.

If this is a chrome problem, an example and a bug report (crbug.com) would be good.